# Error while running JUnit test from command line

Tags: junit

I am trying to run a single JUnit test from the command line but I am getting an error.
I could compile the JUnit test successfully and the class file gets created in the correct location.
But when I try to run it using:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore C:\eclipse\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\JunitWS\SeleniumTraining\src\com\org\tests\Nav.class
```

I get the error:

```
JUnit version 4.8.1
Could not find class: C:\eclipse\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\JunitWS\SeleniumTraining\src\com\org\tests\Nav.class
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDesc
ribbing
```

I don’t know why it is not able to find the class even though it exists in the said location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the class on the command line, not the filename:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.org.tests.Nav
```

From the javadoc for [JUnitCore](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java):

> JUnitCore is a facade for running tests. It supports running JUnit 4
>   tests, JUnit 3.8.x tests, and mixtures. To run tests from the command
>   line, run **java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass1 TestClass2 ....**
>   For one-shot test runs, use the static method runClasses(Class[]). If
>   you want to add special listeners, create an instance of
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore first and use it to run the tests.

and you will have to add the bin directory (note NOT the src) to the classpath of the command line as well. This may look like:

```
java -cp C:\eclipse\eclipse-java-helios-SR1-win32\eclipse\JunitWS\SeleniumTraining\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.org.tests.Nav
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew . I changed the path as you sugested and now it is working fine. Thanks a lot .